# element.animate on svg viewbox in native js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm currently trying to animate the svg viewbox with the .animate method,

i tried

```
  obj.animate([
    { viewbox: 'min-x(' + viewBoxX0 + ') min-y(' + viewBoxY0 + ') width(' + viewBoxSize0 + ') height(' + viewBoxSize0 + ')' },
    { viewbox: 'min-x(' + viewBoxX1 + ') min-y(' + viewBoxY1 + ') width(' + viewBoxSize1 + ') height(' + viewBoxSize1 + ')' }
  ], {
    duration: time,
    iterations: 1
  });
```

which didn't work, afterwards i tried to animate the viewbox defining base rectangle by setting obj to

```
var obj = document.querySelector('#svg0').viewBox.baseVal;
```

trying to animate it like a normal rect, which also didn't work.
Is there any way to do it with .animate?  Or am i forced to use other methods for animating it?

jsfiddle for the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/juwd29s0/

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] so we can actually see what you are trying.  But I can tell you that your `min-x()` etc parts are wrong.  A viewBox is just four numbers separated by spaces. So it is going to be something more like `{viewBox: viewBoxX0 + ' ' + viewBoxY0 + ' ' + viewBoxSize0 + ' ' + viewBoxSize0 },`

Comment: yeah, thats what i thought and tested first, didnt work tho, will edit the example later when i have more time :)